# Slack files: XMLHttpRequest cannot load response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slack-api

Estoy usando `angularjs@v1.3` para hacer un request a la api de `slack`. Según me dice [Slack files types](https://api.slack.com/types/file) necesito agregar el `Authentication` en el header. Hago el request desde `postman` y me devuelve el archivo que necesito.

```
GET /files-pri/... HTTP/1.1
Host: files.slack.com
Authorization: Bearer A_VALID_TOKEN
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: POSTMAN_TOKEN
```

Ahora, haciendo esto desde `angular` me devuelve `XMLHttpRequest cannot load.  Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`.

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: url_private_download,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
  }
});
```

No estoy seguro qué estoy haciendo mal y por qué me devuelve este error, he  leído algunas preguntas similares de SO en inglés pero no me queda claro.

**Actualización:** Al final parece ser un problema con `OPTIONS`, según entiendo de [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request-in-angularjs), `angular`(o el navegador, no estoy seguro) solo evita el `OPTIONS` si `Content-Type=text/plain`. ahora, el problema es que solo lo puedo hacer sin el `Authorization`.

¿Cómo agrego el `Authorization` evitando el `preflight`?

Request actual, necesita el Auth:

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: url_private_download,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  }
});
```

Comment: Hola @learnercys, he estado trasteando un poco reproduciendo el error y no sé si hay mucho que hacer porque me temo que es Slack el que bloquea las peticiones OPTIONS *(la redirección es a la página de inicio de sesión)*. De todas formas me faltaría conocer un poco más lo que quieres hacer funcionalmente y si es aplicación web pura, aplicación móvil hibrida, ... Quizás, si tengo tiempo, haga un ejemplillo en ASP.NET Core que estoy un poco verde en esto de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) y así lo voy aprendiendo (no prometo nada). Saludos

Comment: @rsciriano El problema que tiene learnercys no tiene nada que ver con la tecnología serverside que esté usando ya que el problema se origina desde el navegador hacia los servidores de Slack y esto es un tema de seguridad. Si fuese sencillo de burlar no se consideraría un "mecanismo de seguridad".

Comment: @devconcept Eso lo tengo claro, por eso le pido que comparta más detalles de lo que necesita funcionalmente porque depende de lo que quiera, el camino puede ser diferente. El problema está en que en la petición **preflight** no se incluyen los encabezados de autenticación y **Slack** redirige al login. Bueno realmente, la petición que se supone que quiere hacer no es de API porque es para descargar un archivo. Lo del ejemplo en ASP.NET Core con cosas mías para probar la integración de Slack con ASP.NET Identity. Saludos

Comment: @rsciriano en estos momentos el problema es que al enviar el token de autenticación el navegador envía el preflight y eso no lo reconoce el servicio. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: @rsciriano Eso no es lo que ocurre. Lo que está ocurriendo es que en cuanto pones un header se activa cors. Slack no responde bien y la peticion que quieres hacer no se realiza porque el navegador la bloquea(O sea solo sale el OPTIONS, no el GET). Lee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765

Comment: @learnercys ¿Que hace el usuario con el archivo? ¿Como lo necesita gestionar? ¿Como se autenticas en Slack? ¿Por qué tienes que hacer una petición con $http? ¿Tienes la cookie de autenticación de slack en el cliente? ...

Comment: @devconcept Si, eso lo aprendí ayer, una posible solución sería que la petición a Slack se haga desde servidor que y que haga de puente pero, dependiendo de lo que se quiera pues....

Comment: @rsciriano en estos momentos ese cliente es un bot, y se autentica por medio de un key, acabo de involucrarme en el proyecto y estoy viendo si es posible pasar todo eso al server - creo que no es una buena idea que el cliente tenga ese tipo de accesos -

Comment: @rsciriano Imagine que eso es lo que estabas sugiriendo pero ten en cuenta que son ficheros los que estás manejando aquí. La latencia(y el manejo) que se introduce haciendo eso va a hacer que manejar CORS directamente desde el navegador sea más facil que manejar un puente. Yo he intentado hacerlo antes y siempre es mejor lidiar con CORS(o arriesgarse a crear mala arquitectura). Poniendolo simple, el sistema comenzará a ponerse más lento sin razón.

Comment: @learnercys Podrías dar un poco más de detalles sobre tu proyecto para así ayudarte mejor? Que es lo que se quiere lograr con el bot?

Comment: @devconcept no sé como esos detalles puedan ayudarte - y es un poco confidencial, perdón - Lo que si puedo decirte es lo que ya se encuentra en la descripción de la pregunta, simplemente necesito descargar un archivo protegido. sin tener que pasar por un server intermedio ( a no ser que crean que es la mejor solución, y por qué sería )

Comment: @learnercys Usar un server intermedio no es una solución porque hace que tu aplicación sea como mínimo 2X mas lenta que con otras soluciones e introduce nuevos problemas que no tenías antes. Es mejor lidiar con cors pero me resulta raro que slack no los soporte. Todas las respuestas de SO apuntan a estar usando https en lugar de http o viceversa para que salga ese error. De todas formas cuando necesites descargar el fichero vas a tener que usar el token en la query ya que [no se puede descargar ficheros con ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La razón por la que te está dando ese problema es porque los [preflights](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request) tienen que ser autorizados por el servidor usando CORS[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)[<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)[<sup>3</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), este es un mecanismo de seguridad que funciona automaticamente en los navegadores pero *Postman* no es un navegador así que el preflight nunca se realiza y las cabeceras `Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers` y `Access-Control-Request-Method` no son añadidas automáticamente y los mecanismos de seguridad del servidor no se activan.

Poner el `Content-Type` en `text/plain` no ayudará ya que al poner un header de `Authorization` ya no es una "petición simple". Cualquier petición que potencialmente pueda modificar datos ya no clasifica como una "petición simple". Esta es la definición:

Debe realizarse con un "método simple" que es una petición realizada con uno de los siguientes verbos http:

1. `GET`
2. `POST`
3. `HEAD`

Debe realizarse con solamente con "cabeceras simples" que son algunos de los siguientes `headers`:

1. `Accept`
2. `Accept-Language`
3. `Content-Language`
4. `Content-Type` si es uno de `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`

En tu caso estas usando un header `Authorization` por lo que el cors se activará aunque cambies el Content-Type. Este es un mecanismo que no puede ser evitado ya que es una parte crucial de la seguridad en la web para evitar ataques como el [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Angular usa json por defecto para su Content-Type y creo que Slack no lo soporta

[Sending json to slack in a http post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905260/sending-json-to-slack-in-a-http-post-request)

Así que deberías hacer esto en un `config block`

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8';
```

O en un `run block`

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8';
```

Una solución puede ser mandar el token de autorización en la query usando GET. Esta solución nunca me ha gustado ya que usar GET para transmitir información sensible no es una buena idea. Lee para más información

[Is an https query string secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-16#section-4.3.

Esto también requeriría que Slack soporte este tipo de autenticación lo cual me parece que es posible usando un parámetro `token` en la query https://api.slack.com/faq#authentication

Esta sería una forma de hacerlo

```
$http(
    method: 'GET',
    url: url_private_download + '?token=' + token,
    headers: {
        // Este header no es necesario si ya lo definiste usando headers.commons
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8'
    }
});
```

La otra solución es obtener permiso usando todo el flujo del servidor pero segun tengo entendido Slack soporta cors así que verifica que estes usando **https** y no **http** para hacer tus peticiones, esta respuesta puede estar relacionada:

[Post request firebase response for preflight is invalid redirect cors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35000218/4541024)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que [devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) lo explicando muy bien en su respuesta. Yo estuve trasteando con CORS y Slack y he decidido reescribir mi respuesta con lo que he averiguado por aportar algo mas.

La petición que estás intentando hacer para descargar un archivo requiere autenticación, este fué un cambio que introdujeron en enero del 2016 y que lo anunciaron con este [artículo en ingles](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/important-changes-to-files-in-the-web-api-eb38f2a9c1e7#.vusxt8si2)

Por lo tanto la petición de descarga de archivos debe incluir el encabezado de autenticación.

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: url_private_download,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8'
  }
});
```

Y, como ha explicado [devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept), esta petición activa el modo preflight enviando una primera petición `OPTIONS` que no incluye el encabezado `Authorization`. Cuando  **Slack** recibe esa petición responde con un `HTTP 301' con la redirección a la página de inicio de sesión porque esa petición requiere autenticación, es decir, Slack no está preparado para esta petición.

Desde cliente se podría hacer una petición de descarga de archivo sin incluir el encabezado `Authorization` pero habiéndose autenticado previamente en Slack con usuario y contraseña, porque la autenticación se realizaría a través de la cookie.

El código sería este: *(aunque no tiene mucho sentido hacer esto desde cliente)*

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: url_private_download,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8'
  }
});
```

**Definitivamente, y según decías en un comentario que se trataba de un bot, creo que estás haciendo en cliente algo que deberías estar haciendo en servidor y quizás estás exponiendo información sensible que podría usar en tu contra un usuario malicioso.**

Muchas veces no reparamos en las cuestiones de seguridad pero son muy importantes, a mí [esta](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/NET-Conference/2016/Some-dirty-quick-and-well-known-tricks-to-hack-your-bad-NET-WebApps) charla que  Chema Alonso dio en la DotNetSpain 2016 me hizo concienciarme aún más con ello.

Espero haber aportado algo con mi respuesta, saludos.

**Actualización 28/03/2016:** Aclarar la parte de la redirección a la página de inicio de sesión de Slack, motivada por el comentario de [devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept)

Comment: No funciona :( justo como puedes ver en la actualización, al agregar el `Authorization` el preflight se activa y regreso al error inicial. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @learnercys Creo que añadiendo el encabezado de Cache-control podría funcionar pero no estoy seguro. Ya me contarás

Comment: no lo arregla ): el principal problema es que al agregar headers extras(incluyendo el `Cache-Control`) el navegador automáticamente agrega el preflight

Comment: @learnercys Me lo temía porque no he podido probarlo. Podrías intentar es usar el XMLHttpRequest "en crudo". En [este](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) artículo de MDN comentan como evitar el preflight. En este mismo artículo hay una parte en la que hablan del envío de credenciales configurando `withCredentials = true`, ¿quizás con esa opción funcione? A ver si tengo un rato para probarlo porque me parece interesante

Comment: @rsciriano Tienen un pequeño error en tu respuesta. "que Slack corta, redirigiendola a la página de inicio de sesión". Es el navegador el que corta la petición; el servidor sólo responde con error o no responde y el navegador automaticamente cancelará la llamada a Ajax. Recuerda también que se usa angular por lo que la interacción con Slack es contra su api con el servicio `$http` usando ajax directamente, no navegando páginas. Slack implementa [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/) como mecanismo de seguridad no cookies. Hacer transload de ficheros en el server crea más problemas de los que resuelve.

Comment: @devconcept He actualizado la respuesta para aclararlo mejor, aunque realmente creo que se está haciendo algo desde clientes que debería hacerse en servidor ¿que se hace con los archivos descargados? ¿que credenciales se están usando? Me siguen faltando detalles funcionales

Comment: @rsciriano En realidad es todo lo contrario. Imagina un fichero de 700 Mb desde Slack hacia tu servidor y luego hacia el cliente; luego imagina 200 de esos. El tiempo **siempre** será como mínimo el doble para cada fichero que transportes. ¿Que pasa si me quedo sin espacio? No puedes asumir que este es infinito. Aunque borres ficheros no puedes predecir cuanto almacenamiento vas a usar en un momento determinado y que el borrado sea libre de errores. Esto es solo la punta del iceberg. Resumiendo muy mala arquitectura o un gasto enorme de dinero para intentar sostenerla.

Comment: Lo que no me gustó de tu respuesta es que argumentas que se debe cambiar de tecnología porque hacer esas cosas desde el cliente "no es seguro". Hacerlo desde el server "tampoco es seguro" ya que un atacante puede estar escuchando en el trayecto o haber intervenido tu servidor. Las credenciales en la query son desaconsejadas pero viajan encriptadas, para que un atacante las consiga tiene controlar un proxy intermedio. Los tokens de OAuth expiran, si encuentras un token 2 meses despues es posible que ya no sea valido. Resumiendo usar angular no es muy diferente de usar otra tecnología.

Comment: Hola @devconcept, se me quedan cortos los comentarios así que he creado [esta sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37631/slack-files-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redire) por si quieres seguir hablando del tema

Answer (score 1):

En resumidas cuentas y respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> ¿Cómo agrego el Authorization evitando el preflight?

Como lo tienes está bien, lo que pasa es que como comenta @devconcept los navegadores hacen algo que se llama el **preflights** antes de la petición real. Debes dejarlo como está y manejar del lado del backend las peticiones **OPTIONS** para dejarlas pasar en caso de que tengas un filtro u otro obstáculo que impida el paso de este tipo de peticiones. Tambien ten en cuenta el tema de *CORS* que no es mas que la seguridad que se implementa para solicitudes **AJAX** de recursos cruzado o fuera del alcance del proyecto actual, es decir fuera de los limites del proyecto.

Por otro lado te recomiendo usar $resource en lugar de $http. En [esta página](http://kenhowardpdx.com/blog/2015/05/difference-between-angulars-http-and-resource-services/) puedes encontrar información que compara estos objetos.