# Problemas con petición ajax en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

Hola estoy en un proyecto y necesito mostrar los datos consumidos en la vista final. Lo estoy haciendo es mediante POST de la siguiente manera:

En el controller estoy mandando los siguiente parámetros (data) mediante POST,
cuando la respuesta es correcta me muestra en formato JSON los datos consumidos.

Cuando los datos son recibidos los muestro en consola y los guardo en `$scope.posts` para después almacenarlos en `$scope.posts = [];` (va arriba de $.ajax)

[image: Controlador]

Html:

Aquí llamo al controller, indico `posts in post` y los empiezo a llamar para que me los muestra en la tabla.

[image: Html en angular]

En el FrontEnd **NO** se ven los datos como debería y en lado derecho (consola) se ven los datos consumidos que quiero mostrar.

[image: Consola y frontend]

Ayuda por favor!

---

SOLUCIONADO:

Primero cree un service:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despúes modifique el controlador dejandolo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

html así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y front :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos y espero que ayude la info*  saludos.

Comment: te recomiendo que copies la respuesta y la publiques como tal, así aceptas el contenido que has colocado y con esto ayudamos a mantener la salud del sitio (% de respuestas respondidas) Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

La razón de tu problema es simple. Estas usando jQuery para cargar tus datos en lugar de usar el servicio `$http`. La consecuencia de esto es que el angular no "se entera" cuando se actualizan los datos y por lo tanto no actualiza la vista (Ajax es una operación asincrónica).

Lee [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

Cada operación que realiza cada uno de los servicios especializados llama a `$scope.$apply()` para notificarle al angular que debe hacer un nuevo *ciclo digest*.

Llamarlo desde un script o un proceso externo es peligroso ya que puedes encontrarte un error que diga

> apply already in progress

Traducido: apply ya se encuentra en proceso

Solución:

Usa el servicio especializado que angular pone a tu disposición(`$http`) que maneja de conjunto el ciclo de vida correctamente. Cambia tu controller a:

```
.controller('conectados', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('http://saltala.cl/igniter/Apptotem/GetAllTicketsSucursalWeb', {
        id_usuario: '...',
        token: '...',
        id_sucursal: '...',
        id_servicio: '...',
        tab: '...',
    }).then(function(reponse) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
    }).catch(function() {
        // ....
    });
});
```

La expresión del `ng-repeat` también está mal, debería ser `ng-repeat="variable in colección"`, actualmente tu lo tienes a la inversa.

**Update**

Si tu server no soporta credenciales puedes desabilitarlas con

```
angular.module('myModule')    
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
    });
```

Comment: Me responde con un false debe e ser por xhrfields, como lo agrego?

Comment: @HernanHumaña Chequea el update

Comment: eso iria en dentro del controlador? o fuera

Comment: @HernanHumaña en un bloque [`config`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) y se habilitaría para todas tus peticiones automáticamente. Si hay algunas peticiones que deben llevarla en `true` puedes ponerlas al final como un objeto de configuración, lee el parámetro de opciones de [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Que raro aun continua respondiendome con un  False

Comment: @HernanHumaña Tienes alguna documentación que explique como se deben hacer las peticiones? Yo tuve que deshabilitar el header `Accept` y `Content-Type` nada mas que para que el servidor me respondiera. El problema que falta es de simple configuración. La respuesta está bien.

Comment: Sin la extencion de CORS de google chrome no me deja mandar peticion

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en tu `ng-repeat` tienes `posts in post` pero en los `<td>` usas `{{post.numero}}`.

Neceistas usar `{{posts.numero}}`. `post` contiene todos los datos pero `posts` contiene cada data en el JSON y te permite acceso a cada dato.

Answer (score 0):

Ya Solucione lo de post, entendí que al hacer una petición ajax como explicaba el amigo, angular no se entera y por ende no me muestra los datos y para que me reconociera los datos modifique la linea que se encarga de guardar los datos:

$scope.posts = data.data

Cree un boton en el html:

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="conectandos()" class="btn btn-success" name="button">click</button>
```

y al darle click me muestra los datos...

es decir carga el controlador, Intente con post, cambie el controlador pero me retornaba false! y eso no me sirve, por eso llegue al boton como solucion momentaneamente pero quisiera tener una definitiva.

saludos.

y es asi como voy hasta ahora.

Comment: No publiques datos adicionales como una respuesta. Edita la pregunta y agrega esa información. La razón por la que el servidor no te responde puedes encontrarla [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5838/2224). La razón por la que el botón te muestra los datos es porque hace que el angular refresque la vista pero evidentemente no es una buena solución de diseño. Lo ideal es que sea la misma llamada Ajax la que lo haga en el momento que lleguen los datos. Lee el link que te puse para que sepas como solucionar los problemas de CORS.

Comment: Entendido, a penas tenga tiempo modificare todo, gracias.